# PHPUnit does not work after upgrade to 4.0.4

Tags: php, phpunit

This morning I updated my phpunit version from 3.7.x to 4.0.x.

I usually run PHPUnit with a bootstrap which contains

```
require('PHPUnit/Framework/Assert/Functions.php');
```

Since the update, when I try to run my phpunit tests, it fails because of the following error:

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Framework/Assert/Functions.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php/:/usr/local/share/pear/') on line 6
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Can you check the path of the Functions.php file? is the file still there?

Comment: It's not, but I'm guessing it is location in the phpunit.phar file

Answer (score 1):

That file changed location. It is now in `src/Framework/Assert/Functions.php`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either => Warning: require(src/Framework/Assert/Functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Well, "it does not work" isn't really a problem description. What kind of PHPUnit installation are we talking about?